# var declaration with type vs without

Tags: swift

What is the difference between this

```
var a = ClassA()
```

and this

```
var a: ClassA = ClassA()
```

Why do one vs the other?

Comment: Apple calls these [type annotations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html), for some reason, and not something more familiar like "type signature" or "data type". Probably because "data type" refers to the type itself and not the notation used to declare it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a Swift developer but I'm fairly certain that it operates in the same way as languages like C# in this regard.

In the first case, the type of the variable is inferred from the type of the expression used to initialise it.  Your `a` variable is thus of type `ClassA` and can thus refer to any object that is that type or is derived from it.  In the second case, you are specifying that the variable is type `ClassA` explicitly rather than allowing it to be inferred.

In that second case, the annotation is redundant because the specified type is the same as that which would be inferred anyway.  If those types were different though, then it would be worthwhile, e.g.

```
var a: BaseType = DerivedType()
```

In this case, the variable is being initialised with an object that is one type but the variable is specified to be a type that is more general.

If you are declaring a variable without initialising it then you need an annotation too, because there is no initialising expression from which to infer the variable's type.

Comment: Everything in your answer is spot on: Swift really isn't any different from other languages here. There's also the fairly common use case of creating a float or double using an int literal, e.g. `var a = 1` vs `var a:Double = 1` which, again, works the same elsewhere.